# how to avoid spaces in *ngFor loops in angular?

Tags: angular, for-loop

Im creating a Star-Rating Component in Angular using [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/) `fa fa-star`  and `far fa-star`.

This is the HTML Output, I want inside my component.

```
<div style="font-size: 80%">
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

[image]

If I do this with a Loop, I'm somehow getting spaces between the stars

```
<div style="font-size: 80%">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5]">
        <i class="{{i <= 4 ? 'fa' : 'far'}} fa-star"></i>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

[image]

But it is fixed by making the loop a oneliner. So either deleting newlines in the code or switching the `*ngFor...` part to the `<i>` Tag and deleting the `<ng-container>` will fix the issue.

```
<div style="font-size: 80%">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5]"><i class="{{i <= 4 ? 'fa' : 'far'}} fa-star"></i></ng-container>
</div>

<!-- Both work -->

<div style="font-size: 80%">
    <i *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5]" class="{{i <= 4 ? 'fa' : 'far'}} fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

---

> So how do I achieve this without making sure that the `ngFor` loop is only on one line?
>
> How to prevent the space when the iteration body has a newline?

Comment: So do you want that without forloop? So try hardcoded icon

Comment: Adding `*ngFor` on the `ngContainer` replicates **that**, not the the `<i>` alone, and it's better practice to use it only where you need it, which in this case is directly on the `<i>` tag as you've done in the later example. It's not spaces, it's the `ngContainer` itself that's causing the spaces. You're concise enough to not require any further changes in the second way. Don't fix what isn't broken.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale No, the hardcoded variant is just for the sake of demonstration.

Comment: @LuckyLikey Actually unable to understand the question! Can you describe it? with Expected and Current result!

Comment: @AjitZero good point. However while the `<ng-container>` doesn't appear on in the `HTML` markup, I don't understand why it inserts newlines.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale the first, hardcoded variant is the expected result. I tried to do it dynamic, thats the 2nd codeblock. But that did awkwardly add some spaces. So I figured how to solve it in the 3rd codeblock. The Question is as written in the Title _how to avoid spaces in *ngFor loops in angular?_

Comment: @LuckyLikey unable to reproduce:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-23ozms

Comment: @PrashantPimpale interresting. Do you know, if stackblitz uses windows or unix style line-endings? I'm using Windows btw.

Comment: @LuckyLikey Actually I don't know exactly!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale wasn't able to find any information about that. However user rh16 seems to be able to reproduce it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of `<i>` tags being inline, so HTML treats whitespace between them as space.

One workaround would be to set the font-size to zero and un-zero it on the child elements:

```
<div style="font-size: 0">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5]">
        <i style="font-size: 80%" class="{{i <= 4 ? 'fa' : 'far'}} fa-star"></i>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

You can read more about the problem and this and other solutions in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: sounds about right. I wonder why I didn't find this article myself. Thank you.